# Deleting driectory deletes only its content using Ant

Tags: ant, delete-file

I'm trying to delete directories and its content using ant, but onlt the content gets deleted. The directory is still existing.
What am I miising?

```
<delete failonerror="false">
   <dirset dir="C:\profile\${profileName}\installedApps\Cell${profileName}">
    <include name="${projectName}**/*"/>
   </dirset>
</delete>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `delete` task with the `dir` attribute set to the parent directory:

```
<delete dir="C:\profile\${profileName}\installedApps\Cell${profileName}" />
```

Edit: In response to your comment, here's how to delete all of the directories (and their files) with a certain name pattern that exist within a parent directory.

```
<property name="profile.dir" location="C:\profile\${profileName}\installedApps\Cell${profileName}" />

<delete>
    <fileset dir="${profile.dir}" includes="${projectName}*/**/*" />
    <dirset dir="${profile.dir}" includes="${projectName}*/**" />
</delete>
```

Setting the `profile.dir` property prior to running the delete task is of course optional, but recommended.

Comment: I don't want to delete the Cell<profileName> directory, only the directories inside that start with projectName (multiple directories) ant its content

Comment: Updated the answer.